# A whiteboard software for Mac

Tags: macos, drawing

I'm looking for a software which allows you to simply "draw" on the screen, as if it was a giant whiteboard. It's crucial that the application i able to run in full screen mode. A Wacom tablet will be used as input device.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can try https://presentify.compzets.com/ –– A simple whiteboard app for mac. _Disclosure: I am the developer of this app._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Scribbles, I use it all the time with a Wacom Intuos 4. Actually, my 4 yr old son uses it, too, and when he sees me working at home, we need to paint stuff.

when switched to full screen, it also turns off the dock reappearing (if it's set to hide), only the menu bar will appear once the cursor touches the top edge of the screen.

http://www.atebits.com/scribbles/

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: no problem :-) just be prepared that everyone you show it to will want to spend some time with it...

Answer (score 1):

Omnidazzle allows you to scribble on the screen. It also works on the top of Keynote, where you can have an empty slide to create the "whiteboard" effect:

http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle

Answer (score 1):

[OpenBoard](http://www.openboard.ch/) is an interactive whiteboard for schools and universities

I actively use it to share my screen and draw on it using a wacom tablet

(It is a fork of Open-Sankoré)

EDIT (in my previous post, I talked about open-sankoré but it is discontinued):

Have a look to Open-Sankoré: http://open-sankore.org

It allows to draw on the screen as a whiteboard, but also to import pictures (or PDF documents) and draw over their content.

Answer (score 0):

[Whiteboard](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/whiteboard-collaborative-drawing/id412312635?mt=12) or [Sketchbook Express](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sketchbook-express/id404243625?mt=12) both seem good and are free.

Comment: I've already seen those two. Unfortunately, none of them runs in full screen.

Comment: Oh, that's a bit rubbish isn't it! It seems a focus of Lion is running apps full screen – perhaps they will update to add functionality once Lion is out.